# How to i create a Particle system in unity5?

Tags: unity, particles

how to i create Particle system in unity 5 like a fire, smoke and other types of particles by using unity 5.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you expecting? What's not working with it? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Unity has built-in particle system. Check the docs.

Comment: Please check http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and the other questions of this site to understand how this site works and how you are supposed to ask questions. Your other question also got downvoted and closed but that didn't seem to trigger you to read the on-topic section...

Comment: actually i don't know how to edit the particle system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the built in [Unity particle system](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html). Additionally, there's a number of [Unity beginner tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/live-training-archive) (which I think would be great for you), including one for the [particle system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/particle-systems).

You can get started very quickly by creating a particle emitter via the Unity Editor topbar menu:

> GameObject -> Create Other -> Particle system

This will place a particle generator in your scene. From there you can use the Inspector to change the values of the `Particle System` script attached to the object you just created. Tweak the values and see what the results are live in the editor.

Creating different effects is really up to you. Only you know what you want them to look like. You just need to learn the options available to you and create the effects you want from there.